# How do I wire a bathroom exhaust fan/light to two switches?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, wiring, exhaust-fan

I could use a diagram to wire the following: a bathroom exhaust fan with light on two separate switches. I also need a 3<sup>rd</sup> switch for a vanity light and a GFCI. My power comes from the attic (12/2 with ground). I have pulled a new 14/2 with ground wire from the attic to the 1<sup>st</sup> double gang box in the bathroom. I have also installed a 2<sup>nd</sup> double gang box for the vanity light switch and GFCI - I'm just not sure how to hook things up. If it'll help make things easier I can pull the 14/2 with ground wire coming from attic to 1st double gang box replace it with a 14/3 with ground wire. If more info is needed please ask.

Comment: I understand you to mean you are extending a 12/2 cabled 20 amp circuit in the attic with 14/2 cable? Not good! 14/2 cable can only carry 15 amps and is illegal to use in 20 amp circuits, no matter how small the connected load. Other than that, your project sounds feasible, someone should get you pointed in the right direction soon with a diagram.

Comment: Aside from mixing wire gauges as bcworkz pointed out, 14/2 is absolutely the wrong gauge to use in a bathroom anyway. Before rewiring my own bathrooms, my wife's hairdryer would easily trip the breaker when there was load from something else on the circuit (both bathrooms were on one circuit, I guess it was ok in 1980 but not 2010). That was with 20 amps, let alone 15.

Comment: You should contact a local licensed Electrician.  It sounds like you're in a bit over your head, and could use a bit of professional assistance.  Also. Don't forget to check with your local permit office, as a permit may be required for electrical work in your area.